# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

This is one of the ["real" essential questions of every [public] beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223675/224428):

> ### 1. Who should the moderators be?
>
> Moderators in Stack Exchange perform dual roles. Beside the normal activities of a Moderator, part of their function is to act as liaison — a role which links the Stack Exchange team with the individual communities. Discussing the criteria of a great moderator is important and picking out potential candidates is a great way to introduce outstanding contributors to your community. Stack Exchange is completely open to appointing temporary Moderators when someone’s contribution makes them a standout choice for your community’s human exception handler. If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site goes public. The more guidance the Community Team receives, the more informed is their choice.

For more information about what the pro tempore moderators do, see the blog post [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

---

This question will serve as a "nomination" thread (but keep in mind that the community managers have the final say). If you wish to nominate a user (including yourself) for the position of pro tempore moderator, please obey the following guidelines [adapted from [meta.datascience](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/48)]:

- **Each nomination should be a separate answer.** Link to the user’s profile (main site and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance in a comment, stating that they accept the nomination. Optionally, the nominee can also write something about themselves in the comments.
- **Self nominations are okay**, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

We're looking for members of this site who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

It's also good if the moderators:

- Participated in Area 51, generate social network referrals, or blog about the site.
- Are members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

---

For the moderator announcement, see: [Moderators Pro Tempore announcement](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/148/28)

Comment: I will begin the process of selecting [moderators *pro tempore*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) soon and would prefer to keep the community's input in mind. Who would you guys like to see with diamonds by their names?

Comment: How many moderators are to be chosen?

Comment: Do we have any moderators at all at the moment?

Comment: @FullPeace.org Three moderators. There are no moderators as of this time.

Comment: Does being a moderator put any onus on the type of content one is allowed to contribute to the site onself?

Comment: @yuttadhammo No. Moderators can (and are encouraged to) continue asking and answering questions as usual. They just have additional responsibilities w/r/t flag handling, closing, deleting, etc.

Answer (score 13):

I nominate yuttadhammo ([main](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/18/yuttadhammo), [meta](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/18/yuttadhammo)). yuttadhammo clearly has tremendous domain knowledge (>1500 rep, to say nothing of his demonstrated knowledge outside of the SE network, e.g. on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/yuttadhammo) and [his blog](http://yuttadhammo.sirimangalo.org/)), and has also spent quite some time keeping the site shipshape (84 reviews and 17 edits as of this writing).

(Note: yuttadhammo and I don't have some sort of mutual back-scratching agreement going here; I was going to post this answer along with the question but ran short on time.)

Comment: I accept the nomination. I'm not the most impartial of observers, being a practising Buddhist and Buddhist teacher. I do have a bit of experience on Stack Overflow and more than that on my organization's Q&A SE clone at http://ask.sirimangalo.org/ (which, admittedly, I've let go to weed in the past year). I'm still feeling my way around the moderator tools, and am certainly not as familiar with proper SE etiquette as @senshin, but I am dedicated to making this site a success (even created a [dynamic png](http://static.sirimangalo.org/public/qa_image.php) for your weblog).

Comment: I'm afraid @yuttadhammo, being a member of the most conservative branch of Buddhism, is not the best choice. I imagine a non-sectarian practitioner would be more understanding of various perspectives.

Comment: I suppose that should be informed based on my activity on the site. Do I seem intolerant to various perspectives? Simply belonging to one sect or another shouldn't disqualify one from being a moderator.

Comment: Not saying you're intolerant Bhante (actually, the exact opposite of that so far), just saying any person ordained with one specific school, especially a conservative one, is _potentially_ more biased, hence not the _best_ choice for an objective impersonal judge.

Comment: I guess I don't see how one's school of Buddhism should affect one's ability to be impartial (especially since it is a Buddhist practice to be so ;) ). I would think there are far more important criteria to consider, like reputation and experience.

Comment: I will only be glad if my concern never materializes.

Answer (score 11):

I nominate @senshin, of course :) who better?

https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28/senshin
https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/28/senshin

Comment: I accept the nomination. A few relevant details: (1) I am not a practicing Buddhist (I am non-religious). My interest in Buddhism (particularly the various Japanese schools) is primarily of an academic nature. (2) I have experience using all the moderation tools available to non-mods over at [anime.se] - which is totally unrelated in terms of content, but the tools all work the same across the network. (3) I would be happy to handle all the janitorial work so all you proper Buddhists can focus on the important stuff - posting great questions and answers!

Comment: I would prefer either a practicing non-sectarian mod, or a true Buddhologist academician.

Comment: @zvolkov That is a reasonable request, but are there any people on the site at the moment that fall into either of those categories?

Comment: You are right, there are none, that's why I said "would prefer". However, the fact that we don't have better candidates does not mean we should not discuss the drawbacks of existing ones and our preferences. This is the same principle at work as with election campaigns: not measuring our condition against highest values and being content with "good enough" leads to corruption of values doesn't it? :)

Answer (score 9):

I will self-nominate ([meta](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/32/hrafn), [main](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/32/hrafn)). I've been moderating or administrating internet forums for a long time and have experience as a SE moderator *pro tempore* on MA.SE ([meta](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11/), [main](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/11/)), so I've seen a good number of the sorts of curveballs that a mod could expect.

It hasn't been publicly outside of my twitter, but I've also been pushing this site on social networks among friends who I think would be interested.

Comment: Nice, glad to have another veteran moderator here +1

Comment: I fully support this candidate

Answer (score 5):

I nominate zvolkov ([meta](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43/zvolkov), [main](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/43/zvolkov)) as a knowledgeable candidate for moderation. Second highest reputation based on [Area 51 info on Buddhism.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism).

Comment: Thanks @FullPeace.org I've been moderating Google+ Zen Buddhism community for more than a year now and serving as one of the main answerers on Buddhism Q&A community on Google+. As a Google+ moderator I am known for my tolerance, ability to avoid conflicts, and straightforward head chopping action when it comes to breaking the rules. I'm a Stackoverflow user since 2009 with ~10k rep, and a Buddhist practitioner since 1995.

Comment: @zvolkov recognizing you from there is also part of the reason for the nomination.

Answer (score 5):

I hope that whoever moderates will reside in The Four Noble Abodes:

- Compassion
- Loving Kindness
- Empathetic Joy
- Equanimity

My belief is that we have to walk the talk, even in SE. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

General advice - I highly suggest moderators act with as light a touch as possible. The general idea is that this site is moderated by community consensus and it is the duty of moderators to build and maintain a consensus.

It is always better if moderators build community by encourging the sorts of behavior you wish to see from your community.

Examples -

1) Asking for clarification after a down vote.

2) Asking quality comments be converted to answers.

3) Asking quality comments be edited into answers to improve the quality.

4) Editing (and commenting) questions / answers as an example to the community.

5) Participating on meta.

6) Unless there is spam or grossly inappropriate content, allow, no encourage the community to police their own.

7) Patiently explain your reasoning for moderation, ask the community for feedback, and be willing to change your methods if others have suggestions or the consensus changes.

Such a method builds the community without "abuse of power". The more you support the community, and the more you build your community, the more your community will grow.

Answer (score 1):

I also nominate FullPeace.org as for reasons above.

Comment: Thanks Suminda. I humbly accept the nomination. Also in agreement with the light touch moderation as mentioned by @bodhi.zazen

Answer (score -1):

I would like to nominate "Kevin Johnsrude".

Kevin for his attitude for how this should be done in Buddhism and FullPeace.org perhpas as a praticiner (as per profile)

Also Vipassana / Meditation practitioners on the site also should be encouraged to take this role up (or assist as time permits) as they can bridge the gap between theory and practice as Buddhism is very much practical than being a philosophy or a dogmatic religion. Also this should not diminish the opportunity to any body who does not do Vipassana / Meditation. We should try to attract the practitioners more as the site can benefit from their experience.

Comment: Thank you @Suminda.  I am honored to be nominated.  My SE link is http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/50/kevin-johnsrude and my meta link is http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/50/kevin-johnsrude

Comment: @Suminda Nominations have to be one per post, because otherwise up- and down-voting don't work. You can nominate multiple people by posting more than one answer.