# Moderators Pro Tempore announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, address issues and lead the way in site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these community members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community's issues are properly addressed.

[image: yuttadhammo]
[image: Hrafn]
[image: Andrei Volkov]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are many members who are actively involved here and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections after your site makes it through graduation.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. This is a learning experience for everyone.

---

#### Update, May 2015

Hrafn and Andrei have stepped down from their positions. We thank them for their excellent service. After [a short poll](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1515/7) of the community, we welcome two new pro tem moderators to take their places:

[image: ChrisW]
[image: Crab Bucket]

---

#### Update, October 2015

Yuttadhammo has stepped down. Please join me in thanking him for his excellent and thoughtful service as a moderator, and in welcoming Andrei Volkov back to the squad to take his place.

---

#### Update, April 2016

Crab Bucket has stepped down as a pro tem moderator. We'll be reaching out to the remaining mod squad in the next few days to figure out the best path forward. In the meantime, we on the Community Team sincerely thank Crab Bucket for his service on the mod staff here and wish him well going forward.

Comment: Do great things, mods!

Comment: Congratulations to all three of you.

Comment: Congratulations to all moderators. And thank you for volunteering to do the work. Really appreciated

Comment: Congratulations and thank you to our new moderator team of Venerable Yuttadhammo, Chris W. and Crab Bucket. It's a great thing for Buddhism.SE that three such dedicated individuals have accepted the responsibility of moderating the site. We're in good hands. :)   _/|\_

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for the appointment; I think I already mangled [a question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/is-knowledge-gained-through-buddhist-practice-considered-more-reliable-than-that) by converting a non-answer and all of its comments into comments on the question (any way to undo?), but I'll try to be a little more aware of the consequences of hasty moderation from now on.

Let's work together to make this site a great resource for Buddhism on the Internet!

Comment: No way to undo, but as a moderator you can delete any comments that need deleting.

Comment: There isn't ' direct "undo" per-se but you can reverse all the actions. Delete the newly created comments, un-delete the post, then un-delete any comments on the post that need to be put back in place.

Comment: @Caleb I think I did the right thing by transferring it, since it was an argument for closing the question, rather than an answer. Just made a mess of the comments section, but it does outline the arguments made by both sides of the debate to close.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the appointment! Looking forward to this journey.

Answer (score 3):

The challenge I see is staying within the format while at the same time providing an opportunity for people to see into their hangups and advance their Dharma practice. One thing I don't want this site to be is merely a tool for scratching an intellectual itch for metaphysical / quasi-philosophical speculation.

After speaking with folks at Temperance (the mods of Christianity, Islam and Judaism Q&A sites) I'm beginning to think we need to lift the bar for questions. I will start a meta thread soon.

Comment: Andrei, I think, based on recent exchanges, you and I *may* differ somewhat on this. So I think the meta thread you're going to start should be useful. Specifically, I'd like to understand the extent to which this style of site is appropriate to help "people to see into their hangups and advance their Dharma practice". And just in case people think I'm being rhetorical there -- I *do* think it can be, but with certain provisos. (To be discussed, perhaps on your thread.)