# Got 500 rep? Don't forget about the close queue!

Tags: discussion, moderation, review

Stack Exchange sites thrive because of the willingness of their participants to help keep the site clean. [We have moderators](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/moderators-pro-tempore-announcement?cb=1), but ideally their job is to handle the stuff that regular community members can't. They're exception handlers. Most of the work of maintaining the quality of the site is done by dedicated community members like you.

We use [review queues](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/review) to help organize the bulk of the administrative tasks that need to be done. If you have [enough rep to perform an action](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), you'll be able to see its corresponding review queue. If you have 500+ reputation, you'll be able to use the Close and Reopen queues. These queues help questions with one or two close votes get the rest of the five they need to be closed; same goes for the reopen queue - if a question is edited after it was closed, we bring it to the community's attention to see if it should be reopened.

The moderators and I can participate in these queues, but our votes are binding supervotes - so by doing so, we are removing the democratic aspect from the process. These tools exist to help the community make decisions about its own future, so please [have at 'em](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/review)!

Answer (score 1):

Should this be left unanswered, so that it stays in the unanswered list, or placed into an FAQ or help page?