# Update on Moderator Issue

Tags: discussion, moderation

So... we have now finally got word back from all three moderators; we are all in agreement to step down and allow for a process similar to the original pro tempore moderator selection.

Once/if the SE officials approve of the process, there will be nominations, voting, and eventual selection (guided by voter feedback and other criteria) by the SE officials themselves.

Here's the post from the first time around, I assume the process will be quite similar:

[Who should our moderators be?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/who-should-our-moderators-be)

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is good news. Is it too soon to begin a nomination thread?

Comment: Oh - I'm sorry to see you and Andrei step down. I really hope you all keep contributing to the site. And thank you for all the moderating goodness you have bestowed upon us all.

Comment: Oh! I didn't mean that it's good news about everyone stepping down. Just that it's good news that there is progress on this issue. (Actually I'm sure many of us are hoping you'll accept nomination again Bhante.) :)

Comment: I have been around for about 4 months. Not that long time but i have seen the goodness that you moderators have done for the site. Thank you very much for your time, effort and work. Its well appreciated. Looking forward to the next chapter of Buddhism SE.

Comment: I'll post a new moderator thread as soon as things are squared away on the Community Team's end. Stay tuned.