# Who should our (new) pro-tem moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This question will serve as a nomination thread in our search for a complete team of three active moderators, as discussed in [this meta thread](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1462/7). If you wish to nominate a user (including yourself) for the position of pro tempore moderator, please obey the following guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer containing links to the nominee's main and meta profiles.
- Self-nominations are encouraged.
- If nominated by someone else, the nominee should indicate their acceptance in a comment. Optionally, the nominee can write something about themselves and their desire to moderate in the comments as well.

We're looking for members of this site who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Have experience voting, reviewing, and doing other moderation activities.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

The Community Team will select your new pro tems based on the feedback and input on candidates here, but it won't be purely voting-based - so if you support a candidate, be sure to let us know why in the comments.

This thread will be open for one week.

Comment: Is there any appetite for 4 moderators this time? We have discussed it here http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1474/157 and I think there are good arguments for it. The Buddhism SE community was supportive and I know that the occasional beta site does have 4.

Comment: @CrabBucket We're going to stick with 3 moderators for now. Ideally this refresh will give us 3 fully active mods, and we can see how the workload goes for them for a while. Then we can assess the need for a fourth.

Comment: OK folks, I've locked this post (due to there not being an appropriate close reason for this :P) and will come back to announce the new mods in a few days.

Answer (score 6):

Could I put myself forward please. I've found myself really wanting the site to be a great resource for Buddhism and also a welcoming place for new and old. I'd like to help maintain and support it and all that use it.

[Main profile](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/157/crab-bucket)

[Meta profile](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/157/crab-bucket)

Comment: +1 for Crab Bucket's dedication and consistency on Buddhism.SE. During the short time we were "modless", Crab Bucket really did all he could to keep things active and positive on Meta and on the main site. He's objective, open minded and well liked here.

Answer (score 5):

I'm nominating myself as probably the only original moderator still kicking around. I'm somewhat ambivalent about the idea, but it seems reasonable that having at least one of the original moderators on the team could be a good thing.

I've been accused a couple of times of being a bad moderator, but I don't feel that the accusations were valid. I was also absent for a few months, so don't have the best attendance track record.

I've been the only really active mod for the past two months, so the site regulars know whether I'm suitable or not to continue. I am committed to staying active (no more long trips to Asia in the works) for at least the next year if re-elected.

On the other hand, if there are three keen and qualified candidates looking to take the reins, then I'm happy to step aside.

[Main profile](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/18/yuttadhammo)

[Meta profile](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/18/yuttadhammo)

Comment: I honestly don't see an issue with absences (though I did post on meta asking where everyone had gone). People have commitments and responsibilities. With 3 (or 4????) active moderators this wouldn't be an issue - though I think a post on meta to announce absences would be useful. (Incidentally I am grateful of the effort and time Yuttadammo has put into the site and thank you again for it)

Comment: Very happy that Ven. Yuttadhammo is "still kicking around". He brings knowledge, experience and dedication to Buddhism.SE. He's been the only moderator active for a while now and has worked through some tough issues solo and done a good job of keeping things on an even keel here.

Comment: Thank you for running again Bhante. Im happy to see that you will continue on the site. You have brought so much goodness and quality to this site. Your time, effort and dedication is well appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to nominate @ChrisW

[Main profile](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/254/chrisw)

[Meta profile](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/254/chrisw)

---

I accept (because I did say [I would be willing to to step up as a moderator](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1462/could-should-we-hold-informal-moderator-elections#comment1729_1466)).

I have seen [other StackExchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/users/20772/chrisw?tab=accounts) while they were in 'beta', and how people use 'meta' to discuss site policy: hopefully that's useful.

I think the theory is that the function of moderators is to implement site-specific policies which users (the 'community') vote for meta.

I have not ever been a moderator, myself, in the past. I could be just as happy if the site had any of several other people as moderators; but somebody should and I can see why I am nominated.

I have participated, here on meta; hopefully my posts have clarified what my own opinions are.

I worried, that I do not know enough about the subject (i.e. Buddhism) to be a good moderator: that I would not know when or how to moderate (edit or delete) content (questions and answers).

So I created a meta-topic "*Whether and how to moderate questions?*" – and based on the input (comments and answers) from 3 or 4 other people there, I defined [this answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1494/254):

- That answer currently says that most questions are allowed and should not be 'moderated'.
- If you agree, disagree, and/or want to question or change or support the site's policies then I hope you'll participate in decision making by posting and voting on meta.

The [Theory of Moderation](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7/abby-hairboat) which abby referenced in the OP starts with:

> But what do community moderators do? The short answer is, **as little as possible**!

On other sites I see dozens of like-minded, experienced users help to engage other people:

- Use comments to post polite questions or to add small details to other people's answers.
- Vote (up-vote) all useful answers. An up-vote helps to let other people know when their contribution is appreciated, encourages them to participate again in future, and helps other readers to identify all the more helpful answers.

Comment: +1 for Chris. Check out his network profile. It is impressive

Comment: ChrisW puts a great effort into keeping up with all contributions to Buddhism.SE and is quick to spot problems and offer suggestions on how to resolve them. He puts a lot of effort into researching objective information for various topics being discussed on Meta. He's a natural for this role.

Answer (score 4):

I nominate Robin111:

- People think that she's really nice when she writes to them: which is all-important
- She writes [rules](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1506/254) clearly and carefully
- She's sensitive to the difficulties of editing other people's questions, to make them clearer, and has a track record of having done that successfully (the OP thanks her for the edit)
- Participates on meta (an essential qualification)
- And on the main site, more than [40 answers with an average of nearly 4 votes per answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/buddhism/query/952/top-500-answerers-on-the-site)
- Writes like someone who would be easy to work alongside, on a [team of moderators](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/should-could-we-have-four-moderators#comment1746_1481)

[Main profile](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/143/robin111)

[Meta profile](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/143/robin111)

Comment: Thank you for your kind words Chris. I don't feel as though I have the experience to do this well yet however. (Still pretty new and head down the wrong track quite a bit. ;-) But happy to be here and help out as a regular user.

Comment: I think you should consider your self for the role.

Answer (score 3):

I ask Andrei to continue if he's available:

- Knows Buddhism.SE since Area51
- Experienced as a moderator both [on and off StackExchange](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/who-should-our-moderators-be#comment117_83):

  > I've been moderating Google+ Zen Buddhism community for more than a year now and serving as one of the main answerers on Buddhism Q&A community on Google+. As a Google+ moderator I am known for my tolerance, ability to avoid conflicts, and straightforward head chopping action when it comes to breaking the rules. I'm a Stackoverflow user since 2009 with ~10k rep, and a Buddhist practitioner since 1995.

[Main profile](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/43/andrei-volkov)

[Meta profile](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43/andrei-volkov)

Comment: Sadly, I have to decline. I have tremendously enjoyed being part of this community from the early days, but I have never been an effective mod. Besides, I'm now going through a phase in my own practice that requires me to spend less time online and focus more on real-world interactions. I think @ChrisW will make for a great moderator. Thanks Chris for your trust and support, and good luck!

Comment: Of course you have been an effective mod. `Remember the animals in the jungle... :)` Good luck in real life.

Comment: LOL thanks Chris, that will remain the highlight and pinnacle of my career! :))

Answer (score 3):

I nominate Thiago:

- High reputation (in the top 12) on the main site
- Active with questions and answers on meta (so, interested in how this site is run)
- Clearly knowledgeable about Buddhism
- Patient and methodical: replies to my long questions with long answers
- Also one of the top voters (most votes cast) on the main site

[Main profile](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/382/thiago-silva)

[Meta profile](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/382/thiago-silva)

Comment: Thank you @ChrisW, I'm honored. But I think I feel in the same place as Robin. I don't believe I can be a good moderator at the moment. For now, I'm just enjoying participating as a regular, so I think I'll decline. Moreover, there are already many nominations that I'm very happy with -- I think I voted for everyone here :)

Comment: I think you and Robin should accept this.