# Whom would you like to ask to help moderating here on BSE?

Tags: discussion

Since it's a tradition where task are asked by those who grateful like to make use of others sacrifices, and not a marxist tradition, good householder are possible good encouraged to ask and invite those you would wish to certain parenting your space of Dhammic feed for many peoples luck and prosperty.

Good people wouldn't take care of cattles, yet not even their own. An Jains wouldn't dear to eat their choice and 'selfless' pigs.

So maybe worthy to answer, after having been moved into meta-space.

"Whom would you like to ask to help moderating here on BSE?"

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchanges, worldbinding trades or entertainment, but for an release from this wheel]*

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in this case, in this situation, it would be proper letting go of the tool of voting. It would be the most proper way, if their manager would allow it (possible nobody even knows him...) to go by themselves on search of who could assist, help them. Once found and asked, maybe two, as a matter of respect and care, the elders (moderators, those who actually did the work and sacrificed a lot) might either give those candidates for election, or better, if having found one skilled in Dhamma, skilled in conduct, ask the community for whether there would be a reason not to invite X to assist in the hard work. If fine, fine. If feeling problematic this 'authoritative' act, then go for search for another.

If even such ways are not to grasp by the people who make use, day in, day out: don't wast your time: nothing worthy to gain care for people not aware of goodness, not feeling obligated, not having roots of proper gratitude: the all are equal lost.

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchanges, worldbinding trades or entertainment, but for an release from this wheel]*

Comment: Are you answering your own question using an account with your name reversed?

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it, i.e. asking people to help, asking the community "who would you like to ask?", is approximately what happened last time -- [see here (in 2015)](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1515/254), where several people were invited.

This time the process starts by asking, "who would volunteer?" i.e. "who would be willing to accept if they are invited?"

Comment: It was a good way and it would be good if you here stick with that mode of "ancestor" fist, and conscious handing over ones heritate. Selfnominating is total risky in a lazy community and can also lead to great disappointed in cases a generous person, willing to sacrifice, is't recognized, welcomed and supported. Democracy is only in less cases a tool and actually one of the last. And of course, if a 'culture' doesn't have proper heirs, better to let it die than to make heritage open to all kinds of misuse, good householder.

Comment: As actually father her, it's good that good householder knows his position and even if some criticize, may Nyom go on for good. May he also be well recognized by his 'manager', for them my person traces as the most irresponsible chains in this Brahma-realm. And again, good if the householders try to get BSE out of the commercial interests, and as economical not interesting, maybe the owner is ready for great merits. Then, in this case, you could optimize it to ways of the Noble Ones and their follower, rather then celebrating the Uposata of the Cowards or Jains, like now.

Comment: And, if looking for one in your team, try to look after a better, which might need sacrifices, but helps good householder in grow.

Comment: What about Upasaka Karl? He might be at your age and obiviously has Silas. My person got known a small communityx with a knowledgeable Lay-leader with first right view, from Sri Lanka. Maybe approach also him, since most here are not from old background and marxism hardly dominates (incl of course mainlands, German, France, Russian) https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=10012.0 (nick Maharaja)

Comment: Atma trust that Nyom works on and looks after every good hole the get his good baby well grown according to it's nature.

Comment: @SamanaJohann Thank you for your kind advice. I am happy that ruben2020 chose to volunteer. If I had been asked to do so, I would have invited ruben2020 -- who has been a member of this site for more than six years, who participates regularly, who has never tangled with another user, and who has been somewhat active [here on Meta](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/471/ruben2020?tab=topactivity) too i.e. shown an interest in and understanding of how the site's community makes decisions. I may remember your suggesting Karl, as well, if in future the site must find another moderator.

Comment: How ever Nyom thinks it's good for him and all, and mudita. Nothing must, and sites do not anything *fatzzzz..* (beating with a bamboo stick, since unverbesserlich kommunistisch...)

Comment: It's good now to walk on and leave. Sadhu for all your good efforts, past, present and in the future.

Comment: I could have written, "If the site's community is looking for", or, "If I am looking for". But I wrote, "If the site must find", because it's necessary for the existence of the site -- the Stack Exchange managers do not allow a site to exist (or continue to exist), unless some members of that site's community (i.e. users of the site) are willing to act as moderators for it. Thank you again for your advice, Samana Johann.

Answer (score 0):

Id like Wes Watson to moderate